# Session array being treated differently/overwritten on server but not on local XAMPP

Tags: php, session

I have a site that stores an array in sessions.
Items are added to the array and the array is looped through to display the items.

On my local XAMPP it is working fine but now I've uploaded it, it is showing some odd behaviour.

My array should look like this:

```
Array
(
    [bag] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [item_id] => 4
                    [stock_id] => 7
                    [quant] => 1
                )
         )
)
```

And after I add an item it does but after a few clicks it turns in to this:

```
Array
(
    [bag] => 1
)
```

with the error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /public_html/xxx.php on line xx
```

Is there some session setting I should be aware of for the php .ini configuration or something similar?
(I'm using Hostgator if that helps)

---

A simplified way I'm adding items to the array-

```
function AddBag()
{
//get info
    $item_id   = $_POST['item_id'];
    $quant      = $_POST['quant];
    $stock_id  = $_POST['stock_id];

    if (isset($_SESSION['bag'])) {$bag_array = $_SESSION['bag'];}
    else                         {$bag_array = array();}

//add item into array
    $new_item = array("item_id" => $item_id, "stock_id" => $stock_id, "quant" =>         $quant);
    array_push($bag_array, $new_item);

//update session with new array
    $_SESSION['bag'] = $bag_array;
}
```

Comment: Show how you are entering data into the session

Comment: I've edited my question to show how

Comment: Only this `AddBag` function modifies the `$_SESSION["bag"]`, right?

Comment: No, but if you look at my answer I think I've found what the problem was, though not why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I've found the answer myself-

I have a foreach loop like this:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['bag'] as $bag) {$bag_num = $bag_num + $bag['quant'];
```

This worked fine testing it on my local XAMPP but on my hosting it wasn't having it.
Changing it to:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['bag'] as $bagx) {$bag_num = $bag_num + $bagx['quant'];
```

seems to work though.

I can see why there would be a conflict but not WHY it works on one or on the other, any ideas?

Comment: the `register_globals` setting can be a real wtf when using sessions. check settings via phpinfo()

Comment: Yeah, I've had fun with session settings before! Sometimes finding the error is harder than solving it... Thanks for phpinfo() though, didn't know you could output the settings like that. There doesn't seem to be anything I can see pointing exactly to why $_SESSION['bag']/$bag is treated the same but it should be handy in future.

Comment: because when register_globals is on $bag and $_SESSION['bag'] are the same variable(php makes a reference variable for you).

Comment: Thanks, I see it now- it is turned off on my local but turned on on the server.